# Display selected child product instead of parent product in order email

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2.3, customer selects specific product from configurable product and place order. Now every where(checkout, order and invoice) child product shows but in order email confirmation parent product showing instead of that child product.

Please anybody can help me where I need to make changes.

Thank you

Comment: Anybody knows, how can we do?

Comment: is parent product image showing right now?

Comment: Hi Amit, we are not displaying image in email.